# Take only the lines with numbers with egrep

Tags: regex, bash, grep

i have a file where lines have numbers with characters,only characters and only numbers. I would like to choose the lines with only numbers. I tried `egrep '[^[:alpha:]]' filename` but i take also lines with chars. Any idea?

```
AQ
Feb 9, 1999
11:45
45
```

And i want only

```
45
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, kindly post sample Input and sample expected output too in `{}` button called CODE TAGS.

Comment: hello world 123 , 66, the world and i would like to take only 66

Comment: Kindly add in your post in CODE TAGS `{}` button.

Comment: {egrep '[^[:alpha:]]' filename} something like this?can't understand sorry

Comment: you have to EDIT your post(question which you posted) and while editing use `{}` button by selecting all your samples and clicking on that button(which is called CODE TAGS) eg--> `hi test code`

Comment: maybe now it is better

Comment: Please add samples in your post too now.

Comment: when you say samples you mean what?sorry i am new here

Comment: samples like file: `abc123
123dwdwd` etc etc.

Comment: Samples of the filename or the lines in the file?

Comment: lines in the files and after running command how they should come too in code tags please.

Comment: Do you have any negative numbers in your file, and should they be selected or not? What about real numbers with a decimal point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex needs to check that everything on the line is numeric.  So a `^` and `$` around the expression is needed to match from the start to the end of each line.  Also the match will need to be explicitly for digits, rather than non-alpha.

E.g.

```
 egrep '^[[:digit:]]+$' filename
```

This worked well against the example in the question.

Comment: This takes all the lines where numbers exists. This is not the result i want. I want only the lines witch have only numbers and not chars

Comment: @andrikoulas, as I already mentioned please mention the samples in your post in code tags.

Answer (score 1):

I would *exclude* any line that contains any *non-digit* character:

```sh
grep -v '[^[:digit:]]' file
# ........| negates the character class
```

Answer (score 0):

with `awk`

only lines with digits and nothing else

```
$ awk '/^[0-9]+$/' file
45
```

or, exclude any line which has a not digit char

```
$ awk '!/[^0-9]/' file
45
```

Answer (score 0):

To match lines containing only numbers, use either "whole line mode" with `-x`:

```
grep -xE '[[:digit:]]+' file
```

or add the line start/end anchors to the regular expression:

```
grep -E '^[[:digit:]]+$' file
```

Note that you can replace the character class `[:digit:]` with the range `0-9` if you are only concerned with matching the ASCII characters from 0 to 9:

```
grep -xE '[0-9]+' file
```